# Set EditText above listview with swiperefreshlayout

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to put EditText above listview but I don't understand why listiview is overlapping over edit text. Here is the layout source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
   >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textEnter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextInput"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textEnter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/sw_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!--layout which should be refreshed should come here-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@drawable/customshape"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        >
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I had tried everything that was on my mind and in Android Studio designer there is error like Layout fidelity warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add just this line `android:layout_below="@+id/firstlayout"`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/sw_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstlayout"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@drawable/customshape"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false" >
</ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: for some reason now the listview disappeared